# acts_as_taggable_on multiple fields query using an OR

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5, acts-as-taggable-on

So i’m trying to write a query to fetch users based on the skills they have, the implementation goes like this :

A user has primary and secondary skills, both using `acts_as_taggable_on`

this is the scope i’ve got now

```
scope :by_skills, (lambda do |primary, secondary|
  if primary.present? && secondary.present?
    tagged_with(primary, on: :primary_skills, any: true)
      .tagged_with(secondary, on: :secondary_skills, any: true)
  elsif primary.present?
    tagged_with(primary, on: :primary_skills, any: true)
  elsif secondary.present?
    tagged_with(secondary, on: :secondary_skills, any: true)
  end
end)
```

problem with this now is that if both primary & secondary is present, the query fired would be an `AND` i.e primary and secondary,
I’d like it to be an `OR`, and in no way am i able to figure that out

Comment: damn, why didn't i think of that.. let me give it a try. thanks :)

Comment: did you give it a try?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `or` introduced in Rails 5.

```
scope :by_skills, (lambda do |primary, secondary|
  if primary.present? && secondary.present?
    tagged_with(primary, on: :primary_skills, any: true).or(
      tagged_with(secondary, on: :secondary_skills, any: true))
  elsif primary.present?
    tagged_with(primary, on: :primary_skills, any: true)
  elsif secondary.present?
    tagged_with(secondary, on: :secondary_skills, any: true)
  end
end)
```

Comment: But i'm going to add another answer which would work for all rails versions supported by acts_as_taggable_on.

Answer (score 0):

I did end up using the `or` method of ActiveRecord which was introduced in Rails 5 as mentioned by @archana.

But before i got to using that i tried to find out another way to do the same, and looked a bit into how `acts_as_taggable_on` is designed.

So even if there are two different associations called as `primary_skills` & `secondary_skills` both are indeed an association with the same table `tags` with a through table `taggings`

That means the `users` table has an association with `tags` table, figuring that out everything was clearer now. The solution goes like this :

```
Users.includes(:primary_skills, :secondary_skills).where(tags: { name: (primary + secondary) })
```

This would work for all rails versions where `acts_as_taggable_on` is supported.